# Mostrar nombre del usuario que inicio sesion

Tags: php

Tengo este login que al ingresar te muestra tu nombre en la barra de navegación. El problema es que no me muestra el nombre del usuario con que ingresas sino que está mostrando el nombre del primer usuario en la tabla.

Este es el boton en la barra de navegación para iniciar sesión. Una vez que inicia sesión con éxito te muestra tu nombre:

```
<?php
        if( !isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ){
?>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">
            <a href="formLogin.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt mr-2"></i> Ingresar</a>
        </button>
<?php
        }
        else{
?>
        
        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <a href="usuPerfil.php"> <?= $_SESSION['nombre'] ?> </a>
        </button>

<?php
        }
?>
```

Aca esta el formulario para iniciar sesion:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
            Email:
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
            <br>
            Contraseña:
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <button class="boton boton-gris">Ingresar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

El login.php

```
<?php

    require 'config/config.php';
    require 'funciones/conexion.php';
    require 'funciones/autenticar.php';
    login();
```

Este es el codigo para autenticar (autenticar.php)

```
function login()
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $link = conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT nombre, id_categoria, id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email= email";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $link, $sql )
                        or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    $cantidad = mysqli_num_rows( $resultado );
    if( $cantidad == 0 ){ // se logueó mal
        //redirección a formLogin
        header('location: formLogin.php?error=1');
    }
    else{ // se logueó bien
        ## rutina de autenticación
        $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
        $datosUsuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $datosUsuario['nombre'];
        
        //redireción a su perfil
        header('location: usuPerfil.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: En el `where` debes comparar con la variable `'$email'`

Comment: Es por que estás realizando mal la consulta, estás comparando email = email, cuando debería ser email = $email. 
Verifica los datos obtenidos, imprimiendo el resultado de la query

Comment: Agregando en `email= $email` me salta un error diciendo: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near... Si no agrego el $email funciona bien el inicio de sesion, el problema es que me muestra el nombre de otro usuario. Debe ser por eso que en realidad esta iniciando sesion con otra cuenta por mas que ponga bien los datos?

Comment: Estás concatenando bien la query ?

Comment: Si, lo revise y la conección al MySQL es correcta.

Comment: Con comillas simples porque es String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta linea de codigo agregale el $email y ponlo en comillas simples

De esto

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, id_categoria, id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email= email";
```

A esto

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, id_categoria, id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email='".$email."'";
```

Comment: El inicio del query debe ser con `"`

Comment: Aunque yo lo hago de esa forma. Tambien podria ser asi:
`$sql = "SELECT nombre, id_categoria, id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email='".$email.'" `

Comment: @JuanRivera Muchas gracias! Era ese el error que tenía. Lo que si me di cuenta que las comillas no estaban bien cerradas en `$email` así que lo solucione así `$sql = "SELECT nomyape, id_categoria, id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email='".$email."'";`

Comment: A eso nos referiamos con la concatenacion de la query @Cloby

Answer (score 2):

Si bien la respuesta anterior es correcta, me gustaria agregar algo

1.- Si estas utilizando estas comillas `" "` no hay necesidad de escapar la variable como lo estas haciendo

```
email='".$email."'
```

2.- Puedes poner pasar la variable sin ningun problema por lo que tu sentencia quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, id_categoria, id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'";
```

3.- Esto te ahorrara dolores de cabeza al futuro ya que si la variable la escapas mal probablemente te salga un error.